# Scroll RecyclerView Scroll to position always on top

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, scrolltop

I'm using linear layout manager and `RecyclerView` with a `LinearLayout Manager` to populate some list of items. When I'm displaying the `recyclerview` for the first time and I use:

```
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(desiredindex);
```

it scrolls to the top exactly where I want.

Now here is the tricky part - When I'm scrolling to top of `recyclerview` (i.e. new items indices will be lower than the `desiredindex`) and I call:

```
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(desiredindex);
```

It still works fine, but  when the `recyclerview` has been scrolled beyond the `desiredindex,` the `recycler view` scrolls such that the `desiredindex` item comes to the bottom rather than on top, but I want the tile to scroll to the top not the bottom.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use `scrollToPositionWithOffset` like this:

```
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(desiredindex, 0);
```

[scrolltopositionwithoffset(position, offset)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#scrollToPositionWithOffset(int,%20int)) forces the indicated item visible with indicated offset. The offset is distance from the top of `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Thanks, you saved some hours of my frustration :)

Comment: ^^ I second that!

Comment: ^^ third one here :D

Comment: `linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(desiredindex)` is shorter and also works