# How can I scroll to a specified item in a RecyclerView based on one of the items characteristics?

Tags: android, date, search, android-recyclerview

I am working on a feed-style app, where a user has a lot of posts in a scrollable `RecyclerView`. I have another `Activity` that the user goes to that is essentially a `CalendarView`, and the user can select a date from it to navigate to in the `RecyclerView`. More on this later.

Each item in the `RecyclerView` is a `Post`. The `Post` class looks like this:

```
public abstract class Post implements Comparable<Post> {
    public String userId;
    public Date date;

    public Post() {

    }

    protected Post(String userId, Date date) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NonNull Post o) {
        return date.compareTo(o.date);
    }
}
```

Note that all of the `Post`s are sorted by their dates inside of the `RecyclerView`. They are sorted so that the most recent posts are at the top.

Inside of my `MainActivity`, I have the following code to set up the `RecyclerView`:

```
myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
adapter = new SocialJournalAdapter(posts, this);
myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Where `myRecyclerView` is a `RecyclerView`, `adapter` is a `RecyclerView.Adapter`, `layoutManager` is a `RecyclerView.LayoutManager`, and `posts` is a `List<Post>`.

Assume that the date that is chosen inside of the other calendar `Activity` isn't necessarily the date of an actual post, but could be any date. So, if I have posts dated Jan 1, 2017 and Mar 15, 2017, and I choose February 1, 2017, the `RecyclerView` will put the post dated Mar 15, 2017 at the top, since it is the first post after that date.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38812653/4816518), I believe that once I have the index, I can scroll to it with `layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(desiredIndex, 0);`, but I haven't tested this out, and I don't really know how to find the `desiredIndex`

Let me know if you need any other information or more of my code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want scrollToPosition(desiredIndex)

To find the desired index, look through your "posts", since this is the data that the RecyclerView displays.